How to implement a deserializer for an array, for bincode
I am making a struct that have arrays, but some of these arrays can have endianness, so I made a kind of wrapper. The problem is that when deserializing such struct, I get error on the visit_seq, it assumes the size of ˋEndianess<[u8, 8]>ˋ to be an extremely big number and thus tries to read something like 397463876483 bytes from bincode.
What is happening? How can the visit_seq know the size of Endianess<[u8, 8]> so it can read just 8 bytes on bincode?
use serde::{
    de::{SeqAccess, Visitor},
    Deserialize,
};

pub struct Endianess<const ENDIANESS: char, T>(pub T);

impl<'de, const ENDIANESS: char, const N: usize> Deserialize<'de>
    for Endianess<ENDIANESS, [u8; N]>
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let e = EndianessVisitor::<ENDIANESS, [u8; N]> {
            marker: std::marker::PhantomData,
        };
        deserializer.deserialize_bytes(e)
    }
}

pub struct EndianessVisitor<const ENDIANESS: char, T> {
    marker: std::marker::PhantomData<Endianess<ENDIANESS, T>>,
}

impl<'a, const ENDIANESS: char, const N: usize> Visitor<'a>
    for EndianessVisitor<ENDIANESS, [u8; N]>
{
    type Value = Endianess<ENDIANESS, [u8; N]>;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("an array of 8 bytes")
    }

    fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
    where
        A: serde::de::SeqAccess<'a>,
    {
        let mut value = [0u8; N];
        for (i, item) in value.iter_mut().enumerate().take(N) {
            *item = seq
                .next_element()?
                .ok_or_else(|| serde::de::Error::invalid_length(i, &self))?;
        }
        if ENDIANESS == 'L' {
            value.reverse();
        }
        Ok(Endianess(value))
    }
}

struct MyStruct {
    something: u8,
    array: Endianess<'B', [u8; 8]>,
}

struct MyStructVisitor;

impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for MyStructVisitor {
    type Value = MyStruct;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("a struct")
    }

    fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
    where
        A: SeqAccess<'de>,
    {
        let something = seq
            .next_element()?
            .ok_or_else(|| serde::de::Error::invalid_length(0, &self))?;
        let array = seq
            .next_element()?
            .ok_or_else(|| serde::de::Error::invalid_length(1, &self))?;
        Ok(MyStruct { something, array })
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyStruct {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_seq(MyStructVisitor)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_deserialize() {
        let payload = [0, 175, 60, 67, 1, 0, 75, 18, 0, 0, 0, 7, 9, 0];
        let my_struct: MyStruct = bincode::deserialize(payload.as_ref()).unwrap();
    }
}

dependencies:
[dependencies]
bincode     = {version = "1.3.3"}
serde       = {version = "1.0.210", features = ["derive"]}


What do you expect the result to be? When you call deserialize_seq, bincode will read the first eight bytes as little endian and use that as a length, which is obviously not what you want.
